# Extending ListView of Windows 8 Metro apps developed using Javascript

Tags: windows-8, windows-mobile, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I am having a simple question

How do I derive ListView Control(Windows 8 HTML5 and Javascript) to make new Control with add on functionality?

I know there is provision to derive using **WinJS.UI.derive** Function but the problem is this function takes Object of BaseClass From which I want to derive my class As per [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229815.aspx).
Since The listview control has Constructor as follows.

```
var listview =  new WinJS.UI.ListView(element,options);
```

Hence I can not write below line of code.

```
var MyListViewControl = WinJS.Class.derive(new WinJS.UI.ListView(element,options), function(element,options){}, {}, {});
```

It will throw exception stating that element and options is undefined.
Can anyone suggest How can I derive ListView control?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to derive from an *instance* of a class, not the prototype itself.

```
var myListViewControl = WinJS.Class.derive(WinJS.UI.ListView);

var instance = new myListViewControl(yourElementItAttachesTo, {
    /* options per the properties on the list view object per the docs
});
```

Comment: I did not got what you are trying to say?
var myListViewControl = WinJS.Class.derive(WinJS.UI.ListView);
I can not write above code line since the derive function requiers object of the class we want to derive as per the docs.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying. This works perfectly; I've just tested it. `WinJS.Class.derive` takes: `baseClass` (param1), `constructor` (param2), and `members` (param3). Param 2 is optional. If you have custom properties add them to the members param (3rd).

Comment: I did. It's above in my answer.

Comment: Will Try and give you feedback.Thanks for you help.